# I just wanted to know that is it possible to read and open pdf file in emulater without installing like pdf viewer

Tags: android, pdf, android-emulator, android-sdcard, android-2.2-froyo

I just wanted to know that  is it  possible to read and open pdf file in emulater without installing like pdf viewer

Comment: If you implement code for PDF viewer in your application then only. Else not..

Answer (score 0):

No, If you don't implement code of **PDF viewer** in your application.

Actually, Android **doesn't support** PDF functionality in their development application. If you implement any PDF viewer code in your application and display from your application, then only it possible, Else you have to install PDF application in your device/Emulator and using intent you can open or Read PDF file in that third party application.